# Xamarin/SceneKit/ARKit : How can I detect multiple objects in a hittest?

Tags: c#, xamarin, scenekit, arkit

I'm writing a small AR demo with Xamarin for iOS 11.3, but am having real trouble getting hit testing to work - specifically, it won't return anything other than the first object encountered.

```
var options = new SCNHitTestOptions();
options.IgnoreChildNodes = false;
options.BackFaceCulling = false;
options.SortResults = true;
options.FirstFoundOnly = false;
var hits = sceneView.HitTest(point, options);
```

`hits` will only ever contain one object.
I see that `SCNHitTestOptions` contains an `OptionSearchMode` property (of type `SCNHitTestSearchMode?`) that might control this behaviour, but in Xamarin this is read-only.

Can anyone advise me on how to allow the detection of multiple nodes in this case?